# Converting array in list custom format using jQquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, html-lists

I have the below array

```
Array
(
    [Visitors Promotion in General] => Array
        (
            [Digital] => Array
                (
                    [Mobile Apps] => Array
                        (
                        )

                [Web Apps] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [Mass Media] => Array
            (
                [Print Media] => Array
                    (
                        [Mass] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[Direct to Exhibitors] => Array
    (
        [EDM] => Array
            (
            )

        [IMTEX Website] => Array
            (
            )

    )

 )
```

I want to display it as list using jQuery. The array size is dynamic

```
  Visitors Promotion in General
      Digital
         Mobile Apps
         Web Apps
      Mass Media
         Print Media
             Mass
  Direct to Exhibitors
      EDM
      IMTEX Website
```

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes i have tried .. but not getting the desired output as expected

Comment: could you please share what you have tried so far. So that we can try on top of it.

Comment: Using jQuery? So your JS is making an Ajax request to get the data from PHP as JSON, or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, it is an ajax call to get the data from php as json

Answer (score 0):

You can try to this using PHP.

```
   <?php
$arr = array(
    'Visitors Promotion in General' => array(
        'Digital' => array(
            'Mobile Apps' => array(
             ),
            'Web Apps' => array(
            )
        ),
        'Mass Media' => array(
            'Print Media' => array(
                'Mass' => array(
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'Direct to Exhibitors' => array(
        'EDM' => array(
        ),
        'IMTEX Website' => array(
        ),
    )
);

echo "<ul>";
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        echo "<li>".$key."</li>";
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                echo "<ul>";
                echo "<li>".$key1."</li>";
                foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
                        echo "<ul>";
                        echo "<li>".$key2."</li>";
                        foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value2) {
                            echo "<ul>";
                            echo "<li>".$key3."</li>";
                            echo "</ul>";
                        }
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }   
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }

    }
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: the size of array will be dynamic... as per your program the for each size I have to define a foreach loop